# sharepoint 2013 upgrade From wss 3.0

Tags: sharepoint, team-foundation-server

I am in the middle of a TFS2010 with WSS3.0 upgrade to TFS2013 update2 with Sharepoint2013 SP1. I have successfully upgraded the content databases from WSS3.0 to Sharepoint foundation 2010. But in the Process Microsoft support fiddled around with some of the errors going from Sharepoint 2010 to Sharepoint 2013 now as I wait for them to get back with me I am trying to solve the issue on my own. As it stands SharePoint 2013 has 2 big issues which I think will solve 99% of the errors. One the "Sharepoint - 80" site is not found (404) I need fix this so I can add the  "Sharepoint Web Application Settings" to TFS. Two the Reports server wizard is not working because of the first issue but once I can get those setup I think I should be good. Is there a way to delete "Sharepoint - 80" and let it recreate its self with sharepoint configuration wizard or simply replace the web.config with a new fresh one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to rebuild each of the web applications